# woocommerce : is_home() not working in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display products on my homepage (home.php), not a static front page, using woocommerce shortcode, and hooking this in functions.php...

Here is the shortcode in home.php :
`echo do_shortcode('[product_category category="stuff" columns="3"]' );`

Here is my code in functions.php :

```
if (is_home())
{ 
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
}
```

I've tried, wp_reset_query() and wp_reset_postdata() but nothing means to work...

Products are displayed, but hooks don't work if I wrap it with if(is_home())...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `is_home()` is not working, try using `is_page_template()`. Currently your homepage is displayed by home.php from what I can make from your question. So you can try this

```
function remove_woocommerce_actions() {
if (is_page_template( 'home.php' ))
{ 
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
}
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'remove_woocommerce_actions' );
```

Comment: Thx Pieter but it doesn't work at all. I have 3 loops on Custom POst type before my woocommerce shortcode, with wp_reset_postdata() at the end of each loop... May be this is a reason ?

Comment: @user2160627 I updated my answer. The fact you are using CPT's doesn't matter. I think the `remove_action` is running to early, and get run over later on. Try adding that in the `after_setup_theme` hook.

Comment: @user2160627 Use the `template_redirect` hook, the `after_setup_theme` is to early

Comment: I'll try this asap and let you know. Thx

Comment: ````is_page_template()```` also won't work if you're storing home.php in a folder within the theme such as 'templates'. You'd update it to be ````is_page_template('templates/home.php')````

Answer (score -1):

Try using the function is_front_page()